# Only show errors from compilation in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, parsing, compiler-errors, eclipse-cdt

In *Problems* I see errors from compilation (with gcc) and from Eclipse internal parsing. There are actually some errors from this parsing that do not show up in compilation.
I do not care about fixing this parsing, but I would like these errors not to show up.

**How can this be done?**

Comment: Personally I build using a Makefile (Eclipse provides one I think, at least on linux) and look at the console for compilation errors or compiler warnings. In my experience, the Problems window is Eclipse is more of a collection of problems from various sources and is not really meant for what you need.

Comment: @BobMorane - I also build using a Makefile, from various sources: Eclipse-provided (less often, it is too basic), hand-written, or from cmake for larger projects. And I also look at the console. But in this way I am losing one of the great advantages of Eclipse (or any other IDE): Navigating an hyperlinked system, in this case double-clicking to go to the problem line.
"The Problems window in Eclipse is more of a collection of problems from various sources" in my case, as of now. But if properly configured it could serve exactly for what I need.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip, I'll take a look at that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors from internal parsing are shown by Eclipse CDT's **CodAn** (Code Analysis) component, which can be configured in `Preferences | C/C++ | Code Analysis`.

On that preference page, you can uncheck the category `Syntax and Semantic Errors` if you don't want to see CodAn errors, and the category `Potential Programming Problems` if you don't want to see CodAn warnings either.

Answer (score 0):

For a general setup for Eclipse, see [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52089383/2707864).

To get a similar result, on a project by project basis, go to
*Project* -> *C/C++ General* -> *Code Analysis* -> *Use project settings* -> *Syntax and Semantic Errors* or *Potential Programming Problems*.